# Bash script: rename output directory

Tags: bash

I did a bash script for running a program (Velveth) that takes as input all Fasta files (.fa) in a directory, and give the results in a new directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename  in /home/lpp/Desktop/test/*.fa; do
    velveth outdirectory 21 -fasta -short "$filename"  
done
```

I can loop throw all fasta files but each iteration rewrites the result in the same folder. How could I rename for each iteration the output directory?

I tried giving the same name as the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename  in /home/lpp/Desktop/test/*.fa; do
    velveth "$filename" 21 -fasta -short "$filename"  
done
```

but it does not work.

thanks.

Comment: What exaclty does not work? Any errors? Maybe you need to create the directory before writing to it... And remeber: The script above only works if your filenames of the fasta files do not contain whitespaces!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would recomment you to do is create the directoy before using it as output and also not create directory with the same names as the files. If you want to put the output in the same directory as the file, I would recommend doing this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename  in /home/lpp/Desktop/test/*.fa; do
    mkdir ${filename%.*}
    velveth ${filename%.*} 21 -fasta -short "$filename"  
done
```

`${filename%.*}` will remove the suffix of the file, thus making `foo` out of `foo.fa`, that way you wont create directory with the exact same name as the file... creating directory `foo` for the file `foo.fa`.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this:

```
I=0
for filename in /home/lpp/Desktop/test/*.fa; do
    velveth outdirectory 21 -fasta -short "$filename"  
    mv "folder/result" "folder/result$I"
    I=$I+1
done
```

it will create files like `result0` `result1` and so on

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to `velveth` is the output directory, and both of the scripts you provided are wrong

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename  in /home/lpp/Desktop/test/*.fa; do
    velveth outdirectory 21 -fasta -short "$filename"  
done
```

**Wrong:** Same directory for all

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename  in /home/lpp/Desktop/test/*.fa; do
    velveth "$filename" 21 -fasta -short "$filename"  
done
```

**Wrong:** Directory is equal to the output file

`velveth` creates the output directory if it does not exist, so I guess there will be no problem if you pass an argument based on the name of the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename  in /home/lpp/Desktop/test/*.fa; do
    velveth "${filename%.*}" 21 -fasta -short "$filename"  
done
```

Given an input file `/home/lpp/Desktop/test/test.fa`, `velveth` will save the output files in the directory `/home/lpp/Desktop/test/test`.

Another options might be to just "add" something to the name of the file in order to setup the output directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename  in /home/lpp/Desktop/test/*.fa; do
    velveth "$filename.out" 21 -fasta -short "$filename"  
done
```

Given an input file `/home/lpp/Desktop/test/test.fa`, `velveth` will save the output files in the directory `/home/lpp/Desktop/test/test.fa.out`.